# Mistakes in DynamicField in solr

Tags: solr

```
doc = [{'id':'doc_1','a_t':'A test document',},
{'id':'doc_2','a_t':'The banana:Tasty or Dangerous'},]
solr.add(doc)
```

after adding the codes above in my pysolr file,I can't search the document using

```
solr.add(doc) results = solr.search("test")
```

apparently there is a bug ,could anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You have to issue a commit before a document becomes available for searching. You can also use the Solr Admin interface to makes queries to see if your query works as you assume (and the index is actually empty) or if it's the query that fails.

The Admin interface is usually available through http://localhost:8983/solr/

Comment: thanks for your answering, the Admin interface really works